# How can i fire an event when the user is Idle

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i fire a JQuery event when the user is gone on idle from the website for a specified time, and reset the timer on mouse move, scroll or on a key press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works by using a setTimeout function to fire at the end of the specified seconds. If basically anything happens during that time (the mouse moves, the page is scrolled, or a key is pressed) the timeout period is reset.

Set the idle period on the third line.

```
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false;
idleWait = 2000;

(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('*').bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function () {

            clearTimeout(idleTimer);

            if (idleState == true) { 

                // Reactivated event
                $("body").append("<p>Welcome Back.</p>");            
            }

            idleState = false;

            idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 

                // Idle Event
                $("body").append("<p>You've been idle for " + idleWait/1000 + " seconds.</p>");

                idleState = true; }, idleWait);
        });

        $("body").trigger("mousemove");

    });
}) (jQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script using JQuery that handles  mousemove and keypress events.   If the time expires, the spinner-wrap event is fired.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var idle = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Increment the idle time counter every seconds.
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 seconds
        //Zero the idle timer on mouse move.
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idle = 0;
        });
        // zero the idle timer on keypress
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            idle = 0;
        });
    });

    function timerIncrement() {
        idle = idle + 1;
        if (idle > 5) { // 5 seconds
        $('.spinner-wrap').trigger('click');
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please use the formatting options properly to show clearly which portion is code and which is description.

Comment: Updated please check